# How can i make a filter chain in the symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, filter, symfony1, chain

I have a work to migrate the project from symfony1.4 from symfony2. There is something confuse me. In the old project there some filter i don`t know how to do the same thing with symfony2. For example

This is the apps/frontend/config/filters.yml file:

```
    rendering: ~
    security:  ~

    filter1:                 
      class: filter1
    filter2:                 
      class: filter2
    cache:     ~
    execution: ~
```

And the apps/frontend/lib/filter1.class.php file:

```
    class filter1 extends sfFilter
    {
      public function execute($filterChain)
      {
        try{ 
              $filterChain->execute();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {

        }
      }
    }
```

And the apps/frontend/lib/filter2.class.php file:

```
    class filter2 extends sfFilter
    {
      public function execute($filterChain)
      {
           $filterChain->execute();
           //some other execution
      }
    }
```

How can i do the same thing with the Symfony2. Anything will be appreciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it mainly depends on what you have to do inside those filters, but in Symfony 2 you should be able to convert them into events listeners; you should check out the list of [framework events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html) from the official documentation.